# Print array length without using predefined functions

Tags: java

*I am new to this programming world. I tried to print length of  the array without using predefined functions.*
 **But when i run my code i am getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6**
can someone please help me to find out the bug

**Here is my code.**

```
public class Arraylen {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] ary = {1, 3, 4, 5, 68, 9};
        int len;

        for(len = 1; ary[len] != '\0'; len++) {
            System.out.println(len);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that arrays in Java are null-terminated?

Comment: You're testing the array that you defined some lines above if it has at some index the value `'\0'`. But you never set it. Thus the loops condition is always true and it iterates over the length of the array.

Comment: I didn't know what is the terminator  of arrays in java. Can you suggest me the better way to find length of array without using predefined functions?

Comment: @Abarna.N Can you please mark my answer as correct since it appears to have solved your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is wrong with using `ary.length`?  `.length` is a property and not a function.  You would not be coding `ary.length()`, let alone that "function" doesn't even exist.

```
public class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] ary = {1, 3, 4, 5, 68, 9};

        System.out.println(ary.length);
    }
}
```

Result:
6

Answer (score 1):

Just use an enhanced for loop:

```
public class Arraylen 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
     int[] ary = {1,3,4,5,68,9};
     int len = 0;
     for(int number : ary)
     {
         len++;
     }
     System.out.println(len);
    }
}
```

This iterates over every item in the array, without you having to worry that the index will go over the array size.

Comment: @JacobG. Sorry, I forgot a closing brace and didn't initialize len. I fixed it.

Comment: You also might want to move the `System.out.println(len);` outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a while loop with a try-catch block to find the length.

Something like this:

```
boolean lengthFound = false;
int length = 0;
while (!lengthFound) {
    try {
        // This line throws an Exception when length is equal to the length of the array
        int notImportant = array[length] + 2;
        length++;
    }
    // This prevents the exception from breaking anything and gets you out of the
    // loop
    catch (ArrayOutOfBoundsException ex) {
        lengthFound = true;
    }
}
// At this point array.length == length
```

Comment: You do realize your code will never throw the exception, right?

Comment: Whoops, copied code from an editor (I wasn't sure if I could just use array[length] on its own or if I had to have it as part of a statement) and forgot to switch 0 for length.  Thanks for pointing that out!